# Jquery validation plugin optional validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started using the validation plugin today, so i am not very familiar with it. Here is the problem. I have a user register form with obligatory fields and a checkbox.When the checkbox is selected another hidden div pops out with more obligatory fields based on the users selection. How can I validate conditionally, without having to execute the same function over and over again for every field of the optional part of the form.
Here is my code:

**JQuery/JavaScript**

```
function requiredIfSelected() {
  if ($('#direcfactur').is(':checked')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

$("#direcfactur").on("click", function() {
  if (requiredIfSelected()) {
    $("#direccionfacturacion").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $("#direccionfacturacion").addClass("hidden")
  }
});

$("#cformulariodos").validate({
  rules: {
    titularfact: {
      required: true,
      letterswithbasicpunc: true,
      maxWords: 2,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 16
    },
    tarjetacredito: {
      required: true,
      creditcard: true,
    },
    ccw: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maslength: 4,
      range: [0 - 9999],
    }

  }
});
```

So if I put `required:requiredIfSelected` on every fields rule is way too much processing than it should be.
I am opened to whatever methods and different approaches because I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: set a global variable? and on change set it.